# c# concatenate List<string> plus string

Tags: c#, arrays, string, concatenation

I have this List in c#:

```
List<string> cad_analise = new List<string>();
```

And I added this:

```
cad_analise.Add("FQ");
cad_analise.Add("CR");
```

So, I would like to do this

```
var joinstring = ""; 

joinstring = cad_analise[0] + ", second is " + cad_analise[1] + ", join the words.";
```

But, I am getting the following error:

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
```

I did some tests here and I fought that the error is when I join the cad_analise[0] and cad_analise[1].

See here the error: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3rowFv

Here is working perfectly: https://dotnetfiddle.net/G6JwFs

Comment: You're using 3 different variable names in your question: `cad_analise`, `has_analise` and `analise`

Comment: what is `analise` I don't see were you initialize this. Do you mean `cad_analise` instead

Comment: My sincerely sorry, now I edited, please answer me if you know.

Comment: @TimonPost, right, I edited now.

Comment: Your code works. There is nothing wrong: See [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RNCNwc)

Comment: Make sure you `Add()` the two strings before you call `cad_analise[0]` and cad_analise[1]. Probably your List is empty and your trying to access  element who aren't there.

Comment: @CodingYoshi, perfect! But please see this https://dotnetfiddle.net/G6JwFs, I have a problem if I did it. I put the line commented.

Comment: @CodingYoshi, I edited the question again, and I also put 2 links: with the error with cad_analise[1] plus string and without it, please see it.

Comment: @TimonPost, can you see the links examples please, I clearer now.

Comment: @kfm: not working because you check number_analise_cad to see if it is 3 but then you try to get item at index 2 of has_analise, there are only 2 items in has_analise not 3

Comment: Why don't you simply use a debugger to step through your code and see what happens?

Comment: I found whats wrong check my answer

Comment: @kfm if you change all your if conditions to use `number_analise_existente`, then it will work because your code depends on the items in `has_analise`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code example https://dotnetfiddle.net/3rowFv you'll have these bools:

```
    bool has_analiseCR = true;
    bool has_analiseFQ = true;
    bool has_analisePCB = false;
    bool has_analise2FAL = false;
    bool has_analiseGP = false;
```

Then you are checking if it's true add a value to `has_analise List<string>` if false add it to `cad_analise List<string>`. So in the end:

has_analise will look like:

[0] => "CR"

[1] => "FQ"

then you are trying on line 74:

```
print_analise_cad = "Análise " + has_analise[0] + ", " + has_analise[1] + " e " + has_analise[2] + " do equipamento " + NumSerie_app + " e amostra de " + data_amostra + " foram cadastradas.";
```

Where you are calling `has_analise[2]` this index does not exits as shown above.
The list only has a value on index [0] and [1] and not on [2]

Also you are checking on `number_analise_cad` `if (number_analise_cad == 3)` and not on the length of `number_analise_existente` whits is based on the lenght of `has_analise List<string>`

This is the reason why you are getting the index out of range exception.

Comment: I already told the OP this in a comment: `not working because you check number_analise_cad to see if it is 3 but then you try to get item at index 2 of has_analise, there are only 2 items in has_analise not 3`

Comment: Guys thank you! The really problem in my code is that I confused my variables, with your answers I saw the error, thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

As you can verify [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ddseY0), your (as posted in the question) code works.

The only issue I found  is a missing semicolon at the end of the last line (but I guess this was a copy/paste error):

```
joinstring = cad_analise[0] + ", second is " + cad_analise[1] + ", join the words.";
```

Comment: No bro, thank you, see the links that I put, I guess now is clearer.  See here the error: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3rowFv

Here is working perfectly: https://dotnetfiddle.net/G6JwFs, it's in the if (number_analise_cad == 3).